# How many 3-tuples of sets that meet the codition are there?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

If $n>0$ ($n$ natural) and $A⊆B⊆C⊆\{1,2,3,...,n\}$, how many 3-tuples of sets $(A,B,C)$ there are?

For $n=1$ there are four of them and I think that for $n=2$ there are sixteen. I don't know how to figure out general formula, so I would appreciate some hint.

Comment: I suppose $1$ could be in $A$, $B$ and $C$, or it could be in $A$ and $B$, but not in $C$, or in $A$ but neither of $B$ nor $C$, or in none of them....

Comment: I think there are 4^n of them, but I don't know how to prove it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are $4^n$ of them, because for each element there are four options,
1)goes in C and not in A or B 
2)goes in B and C and not in A 
3)goes in all A, B and C
4)Doesn't go in any of A, B or C.
and there are n elements in all in the set {1,2,...}.
Hope it helps:)